# Apache ignoring multiple ServerName directives for subdomains

Tags: apache

I got a problem regarding `Apache 2.4` and it's VirtualHost configuration.

I got a subdomain `sub.example.com` and a subsubdomain `static.sub.example.com`. I try to assign different DocumentRoots but with my config below it only leads to `/var/www/html/`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName static.sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/static/
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Additional info: config above is in one file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and of course enabled (as per default). All other configs are unchanged defaults. Server is running on Ubuntu 14.04.

I found [this solution](https://serverfault.com/questions/394182/apache-2-4-first-virtualhost-configuration-loading-for-servernames-of-other-vho) but it unfortunately didn't work for me.

**Update:** output of `apachectl -S`:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server sub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost sub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost static.sub.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:6)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
// Some more lines that are not related I think
```

**Update:** additional information for finding solution:

I got a reverse proxy running in front of my webserver. Extract from `000-default.conf` of reverse proxy (also Apache 2.4):

```
ProxyPass               /       http://webserver/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse        /       http://webserver/
```

Comment: Any other virtualhosts are working? It seems that you do not have enabled vhost functionality at all.

Comment: I think so, yes. I've updated my post with output of `apachectl -S`.

Comment: Make sure your file is included by httpd.conf Include directive (it is usually located on the bottom of the file)

Comment: It is. If I change order of VirtualHost entries I can see content of site static.sub.example.com. But on both static.sub.example.com and sub.example.com.

Comment: ok, it seems that your ServerName directive is either ignored or you are not using exact name in url as in ServerName directive and apache uses FIRST virtualhost encountered as this is default to use when there is no match. Make sure there is no typo in your address.

Comment: I found the solution. I got a reverse proxy in front of webserver and didn't preserved host information. I'll update my question and answer. Thank you for your ideas bringing me on the right track :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding option `ProxyPreserveHost` to reverse proxy's config does the deal:

```
ProxyPreserveHost       On
ProxyPass               /       http://webserver/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse        /       http://webserver/
```